# How to use external actionscript classes in FlashBuilder (thought I knew)

Tags: actionscript-3, class, csv, flash-builder, external-script

I'm trying to implement CSVLib in an Air application and am getting an error that seems wholly illogical to me.

"1120: Access of undefined property csv." 
and 
"1120: Access of undefined property completeHandler."

The only thing I can think is it's not importing the csv class properly, or the class itself is broken somehow?  I know my import path is correct because I typed it out directly based on automatic hinting.  The code below is copied directly from the how-to wiki on the csv lib site.

Or is there something special you need to do to get external actionscript classes to work in flashbuilder?

```
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.shortybmc.*;
            import com.shortybmc.data.parser.CSV;

            var csv:CSV = new CSV();
            csv.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            csv.load (new URLRequest('example-2.csv'));
            function completeHandler (event: Event)
            {
                trace ( csv.data.join('\r') );
                // do something ...
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the problem is somewhere else. The `fx:Script` tag is within a MXML file, which represents a class definition.

Your error happens, because you have code within the class definition (i.e. outside of a method). You can write this instead for example:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.shortybmc.*;
        import com.shortybmc.data.parser.CSV;

        private var csv:CSV;
        private function init ():void
        {
            csv = new CSV();
            csv.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            csv.load (new URLRequest('example-2.csv'));
        }

        private function completeHandler (event: Event):void
        {
            trace ( csv.data.join('\r') );
            // do something ...
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Then you need to make sure that the `init` method is actually called; you can do this in the complete handler of your MXML object.

Comment: ah.. I figured since the imports import in that situation that the script block just plays through like any normal code. But what you said makes sense, and works! Thank you.